# Android google map accuracy issue

Tags: android, google-maps, integer

I am developing android version of an iPhone application. But, I found that in android, google map takes latitude E6 and longitude E6 integer values as GeoPoint argument.

As a result, whenever I have  a lat/long value like 35.1234567 it means that there is 7 digits after the decimal point. As a result, (int)(35.1234567*E6) provides 35123456. So, I am definitely missing the precision as it misses the 7th digit (7 in this case).

So, I found different location in my android googlemap and in iphone map.

Is there anyway that can fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worst case scenario is at the equator where one degree in Longitude is 111.320km.  With the E6 number you are able to represent 0.000001 degree or a distance of 0.11132m (less than 4.5 inches).  You are never going to get that level of accuracy out of a GPS system available to the public anyway, so the loss of a single digit of precision will never be noticed.

Comment: Thanks for your info. But, to be precise, I can find my home by google map and google map provides a lat long value for that. So, in this way, how come i cant really view it vice versa, i.e. through geopoint lat long argument?

Comment: What are the lat and long you get from Google Maps and what are you putting into the GeoPoint?

Comment: I am taking lat long along with other information from database. Here is one instance : LAT: 53.5497918 LNG: -113.4991595 and this value represents a specific position but as I have to convert it int latE6 and LngE6 as a result I am having precision problem.

Comment: This is the code that I use to convert from a Location to a GeoPoint and it works fine for me.  public static GeoPoint locationToGeoPoint(final Location location)
 {
  return new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1000000),(int)(location.getLongitude() * 1000000));
 }

Comment: @CaseyB Do you mean to say that it is not possible **at all** or are there workarounds? using iphone, I can get my location up to an accuracy of: 1.3508868153838107, 103.85198823174314

Comment: Read this from the Garmin website (http://www8.garmin.com/aboutGPS) The gist is that their GPS units can be accurate up to 3m! That means when a GPS says this is the spot it could actually be many meters off depending on factors such as satellite occlusion and weather so the extra decimal points of precision you're looking for are just noise.